# Navigate to the function that is overriden in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have VS2019, and I would like to be able to jump to the interface(in my case) member function/base class member function(in general case) of a class member function I am currently viewing.

Is this possible?

example

```
class B {
    public:
    void Do() = 0; // Where I want to jump
};
class D: public B {
    public:
    void Do() override; // << I am here
};
```

Comment: `void D::Do() { B::Do();}`

Comment: @MikeVine by navigate I meant in IDE, not how to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you could use `Shift + Alt + F12` to find all references to a function.

For example, you could use `Shift + Alt + F12` on `Do()`. Then, the VS will appear a navigation bar called `Find Symbol Results`.

[image]